# Ruby: control which classes are exported

Tags: ruby, module, export

I have a [piece Ruby code](https://github.com/halst/peg.rb) that I want to release. It consists of a bunch of classes. Some of the classes are meant to be exported, other are meant to be private (implementation detail). How do I export just the public classes and keep the private classes—private?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496291/private-class-not-class-method-in-a-ruby-module