# Can I disallow a Rails model from being access outside of a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to have a model such that only code within the same module can access it?

Something like:

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeActiveRecordModel
    # has attribute `some_attribute`
    ...
  end
end

module SomeModule
  class SomeOtherClass
    def self.sum_of_attribute
      SomeActiveRecordModel.sum(:some_attribute)
    end
  end
end

class OutsideOfModule
  def self.sum_of_attribute
    SomeModule::SomeActiveRecordModel.sum(:some_attribute)
  end
end

SomeModule::SomeOtherClass.sum_of_attribute # works
OutsideOfModule.sum_of_attribute # raises error
```

Comment: shouldn't this raise error already? From `OutsideOfModule`, you need to do `SomeModule:: SomeActiveRecordModel` in order to refer to the class.

Comment: True, but not the point of my question. I'll update the method inside `OutsideOfModule`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Here's why

Ideally, you want to implement this in your `SomeModule`. But when you call `SomeModule::SomeOtherClass.sum_of_attribute` in other classes, you are in a scope of `SomeModule::SomeOtherClass`.

```
SomeModule::SomeActiveRecordModel.sum(:some_attribute)
                      ||
                      \/
module SomeModule
  class SomeActiveRecordModel
    def sum(*args)
      # Here, self => SomeModule::SomeActiveRecordModel
      # That's why you won't be able to do any meta trick to the module
      # or classes in the module to identify if it's being invoked outside
    end
  end
end
```

So you wouldn't know who the original caller is.

You might be able to dig through the call stack to do that. Here's another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method) you might find helpful if you want to go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. But this is more a question of Ruby's approach and philosophy. There are other ways of thinking about the code that allow you achieve something similar to what you're looking for, in a more Rubyesque way.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496291/private-class-not-class-method-in-a-ruby-module) covers the different ways of making things private.